# Could two lines behave like one in textView?

Tags: android, xml, textview

I am working on simple android project. It should print some songs, which could be zoomed.

Text of song is divided in two blocks: lyrics and chords.(chord one line, text one line, and so on..)
Like this:

[image]

But when i zoom i get this:

[image]

I need those chords to be fixed to specific words(or letters) in lyrics!

This is what i have in my xml(it is simple textview expanded by zoom activity):

```
<juraj.myapp.ZoomTextView
        android:id="@+id/Song"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text ="A       Fis     G\nI sing song blah\nCis      H-mol\nblah blah blaaaaaaah!\n"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/inputSearch"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:scrollbars = "vertical"
        />
```

Is it possible to represent two lines as one? Or how can i fix those chords to lyrics? Or do you suggest some other solution?

Thank you!

Comment: try to  decrease textview size 20 to 18 or lessthen 18 .

Comment: I don't think you can handle it this way. TextViews are supposed to render text having in mind endlines, text sizes, and some other related stuff, but no "synchronizing" words.

Comment: @SorathiyaPayal why would i do that? I need that text to be readable. Therefore i added that zooming to textview. This will not solve my problem. :) But thanks...

Comment: @jDur, and do you see any other solution?

Comment: Maybe you could build your own text renderer. It is like writing some text in a bitmap, but you have to manage almost all the complex things: endlines, textsizes and your word synchronizer.

Comment: your text are put in @string file , and your xml zoomtextview text  android:text ="@string/test"  may be help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i figured it out with **superscript**. Thank you guys :)